# Proof of Lemma 4.4.1 in Liu's Algebraic Geometry.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The following lemma is Lemma 4.4.1 in Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curve page 149:

> Let $Y$ be the spectrum of a Noetherian complete local ring with closed point $y$. Let $X$ be a $Y$-scheme of finite type such that $X_y$ consists of a single point $x$. Then, $x$ admits an affine neighborhood $U$ that is finite over $Y$.

The proof starts by assuming $X$ to be affine and all irreducible components of $X$ passing through $x$. Set $B:=\mathcal{O}_X(X), A:=\mathcal{O}_Y(Y)$ and let $m$ be the maximal ideal of $A$ represented by $y$. Then, the proof notes that $\mathcal{O}_X(X_y)=B/mB$ is a finite $A/m$-algebra, which is fine. From there, the proof concludes that there is a finitely generated $A$-submodule $N$ such that $B=N+mB$. Then, the proof continues by using a lengthy argument to conclude that $B=N$ which shows the statement. However, when the book reaches the conclusion that $B=N+mB$, why does not the book conclude $B=N$ by applying the Nakayama Lemma to $B/N$?

Attached below is the snippet of the proof taken from the book for reference.
[Proof of Lemma 4.4.1 part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaoF5.png) and [Proof of Lemma 4.4.1 part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HQfH.png)

Also, note that there is a typo in the first picture. $N$ should be a finitely generated $A$-module according to [https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~qliu/Book/errata-third.pdf](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/%7Eqliu/Book/errata-third.pdf).

Comment: To apply Nakayama, you would need $B/N$ to be a finite $B$-module, but $N$ is not even a $B$-module

Comment: @math54321 Thank you for your reply... But, I still do not understand why we require $B/N$ to be a finite $B$-module. Since $m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ (not $B$), shouldn't we require $B/N$ to be a finite $A$-module?  We have $A$ is Noetherian, both $B$ and $N$ are finitely generated $A$-module, and $N$ is an $A$-submodule of $B$,  doesn't this imply $B/N$ is f.g $A$-module? At least, that is what I thought, can you point out my mistake?

Comment: Ah my bad! I mistakenly interpreted $B$ as a finitely generated $A$-module, when it is only known that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra... Anyway, thank you for the correction.